# Ionic2, ion-select multiple - limit user selection

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm new at Ionic2 and angular2.

I use ion-select plugin, and use multiple option.
Is there any way to limit user selection, for example till three items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ionChange event
in tempate:

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="selected_values"  (ionChange)="onSelect()">
                        </ion-select>
```

in ts:

```
selected_values=[];
onSelect(){
    if(this.selected_values.length==3){
        //do somthing
     }
}
```

Comment: (ionChange) will only execute when OK is clicked

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately he doesn't have that kind of support. An alternative would be to add the maxlength directive stating the number of selected items desired. Thus, if a larger value is selected, the field will be invalid in the form.